# Prove that there exists 3 numbers $a,b,c$ so that $P(a)=b, P(b)=c, P(c)=a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, lagrange-interpolation

**The problem**

Given that $P(x)=x^3-3x$. Prove that there exists $a \neq b \neq c$ such that $P(a)=b, P(b)=c, P(c)=a$

**My ideas**

So the conditions here makes it quite clear that I intend to use the Lagrange Interpolation: third degree polynomial versus creating three equations.

It is even more generous to think reversely that if we have 3 functions, then we can still add one other function of choice to re-create $P(x)=x^3-3x$. (Even though I think that function is $P(0)=0$

But still, I can't get the original problem done.

So any help is appreciated!

Comment: Interesting question. Note that if $a$, $b$ and $c$ are solutions of the problem, then they are fixed points of $P\circ P\circ P$, that is zeros of $Q(x)=P\circ P\circ P(x)-x$. Conversely, if $a$ is a zero of $Q$, then you can define $b=P(a)$ and $c=P(b)$ and then you got that $P(c)=a$. Also, $Q$ has degree $27$ so it has at least one zero. Of course, this does not guarantee that $a\neq b\neq c$ (for example, the fixed points of $P$, $0$, $2$ and $-2$ are obviously zeros of $Q$).

Comment: By using computer, $Q$ has $13$ variations in sign so potentially $13$ positive zeros, so hopefully you can use my comment to finish the problem.

Comment: @Taladris Do you mean $P(P(P(x)))$, that makes sense though. Thank you.

Comment: @cineel I was trying to rework on the simple roots part. I didn't expect that to be complicated when I first skimmed through the solution. could you clarify the partition part? (at the end of the solution)

Comment: you dont really need a partition. from 24 numbers, pick a number and call it a. let b=P(a) and c=P(b). if b=c, then a=P(c)=P(b)=c=b, contradiction.

Comment: if a=c, then a=P(c)=P(a), contradiction. so a,b,c are distinct. more generally, any fixed point of $P^n$ must be a fixed point of P or part of an m-cycle, where m|n.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The roots of P(x)-x are 0,2,-2. but all of them are simple roots of P(P(P(x)))-x because
$(P(P(P(x)))-x)'$
$=P'(P(P(x)))P'(P(x))P'(x)-1$
$=(P'(x))^3-1$
$=(P'(0))^3-1$ or $(P'(\pm2))^3-1$
$=(-3)^3-1$ or $9^3-1$
$\neq 0$
$P(P(P(x)))-x$ has 27 roots while $P(x)-x$ has 3 roots, so the 24 numbers which are roots of the first but not second can be partitioned into 3-cycles under the action of P.

Answer (score 1):

So I would like to introduce another solution to my problem, using trigonometry.

So I first notice that if I select $a= 2cos \alpha$, then \begin{align} P(a)=2cos3\alpha=b = 2cos \beta \\ P(b)=2cos3\beta=c=2cos\gamma \\P(c)=2cos3\gamma=a=2cos\alpha\end{align}

So $cos27\alpha =cos\alpha$, which means if I choose $\alpha+2k\pi=27\alpha$ then I get the results.

Many thanks to **@cineel** for your beautiful solution, I really appreciate that.

Also thanks **@Taladris** for the very helpful hints